# Excel locks up when closing Windows Form

Tags: c#, excel

Using C# I am developing an Excel add-in. This add-in opens a Windows Form and needs to set `ScreenUpdating` to false so I am using the following code.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
[...]
ExcelApp = Globals.ThisWorkbook.ThisApplication;
ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
```

So far this works fine. However Excel locks up when closing the form and I don't know why. When removing the following lines then closing the form is successful.

```
ExcelApp = Globals.ThisWorkbook.ThisApplication;
ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
```

Comment: Of those two lines, which causes the lockup?

Comment: It is probably the second one. So just set `ScreenUpdating` back to true when you're closing the form.

Comment: Are you sure your application closes or do you just not see it anymore? Check the task manager and see if it's still running.

Comment: I will check your comments and come back to you later :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = true;` before closing the form solves the problem.